# Incluindo no APK uma base de dados SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, apk

É possível incluir na instalação do APK a base de dados da aplicação? Eu ja tenho todos os registros necessários para o funcionamento da aplicação e gostaria de incluir ela durante a instalação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode exportar o banco de dados como sql e colocar na pasta de assets. Cuidado para que os dados não se repitam (dados no banco de dados atual + dados do sql) no seu aplicativo.

Aqui tem um bom passo a passo: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Seria legal pelo menos ter um resumo desse *link* aqui. Ele pode sair do ar e sua resposta fica inválida.

Comment: Tem também esta explicação semelhante a que o Vinicios postou só que em português.
[_Usando seu próprio banco de dados SQLite em aplicações Android_](http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2011/04/01/usando-seu-proprio-banco-de-dados-sqlite-em-aplicacoes-android/)